# Align all cylinders to point to parent sphere node with geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have this:
[image]

I'd like all cylinders to point to the bigger sphere on the right, while still being attached to their original spheres.

This is my set up so far:

[image]

If I try to use Transform to move the cylinder and rotate on the Z axis, I get:

[image]

Node setup:
[image]

Comment: Basically you have set it up correctly, and the rotation should work on the Z-axis, but try to move the cylinder with `Transform` before the instantiation, instead of using `Set Position` afterwards.

Comment: Sadly that still gives me the cylinders pointing in strange directions. I'll attach an image

Comment: Please check if you have applied scaling to all objects and if you really reference the correct sphere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the question is about this particular case, and not a more general 'point-at' problem..

[image]

..to keep things simple, you could use a cone..

[image]

More generally, to orient cylinders, you need the vector between source position and target position:

[image]

.. whose length can optionally be used to make rays reach the target exactly. (Blue nodes, above)

[image]

[image]

The file also includes an 'instanced curves' method.

Comment: Thank so so much! This is exactly what I was looking for. Do you know how I could change the origin of the object to be at the center of the target ball? (I'm trying to align the target ball to the center of the world so that I can rotate around it with a camera)

Comment: I was referring to the more general case you mentioned

Comment: Hi @Hmm !. Everything you do in GN is to the geometry, not the object that contains it. You can't directly control the object transform from inside a modifier... but if your _modified object_ is at the origin anyway, then just adding [this](https://imgur.com/a/lOf4gem) to the end of the tree will nail the target to World 0.

Comment: Yay! It worked. Thank you again. I eyeballed it with just the Transform: https://imgur.com/a/Ykacfzw